# Dates on x-axis on Google Charts

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I'm trying to make a google chart with prices on the y-axis and dates on the x-axis. I don't understand why my code is not working. It is not displaying anything.

In header:

`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Dato');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Anbefalet pris');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Nuværende pris');

  data.addRows([
    [new Date (2016, 8, 6), 378, 418],
    [new Date (2016, 8, 13), 66, 324],
    [new Date (2016, 8, 20), 254, 257],
    [new Date (2016, 8, 27), 117, 105],
    [new Date (2016, 9, 3), 119, 66],
    [new Date (2016, 9, 10), 88, 77],
    [new Date (2016, 9, 17), 76, 96],
    [new Date (2016, 9, 24), 123, 106],
    [new Date (2016, 10, 1), 66, 148],
    [new Date (2016, 10, 8), 128, 116]
  ]);

  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Anbefalede og nuværende ugepriser',
      subtitle: 'Blå: Anbefalede priser, Rød: Nuværende priser'
    },
    legend: { position:'none' },
    width: '100%',
    pointSize: 10,
    explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'] }
  };


  var chart = new google.charts.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
 </script>
```

In body:

`<div id="linechart_material" class="chart"></div>`

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please correct:  
I'm trying to make a google chart with prices on the y-axis and dates on the y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

material charts use the namespace `google.charts`

core charts use the namespace `google.visualization`

so for *core chart* line chart -- `google.visualization.LineChart`

for *material* line chart -- `google.charts.Line`

see following snippet, which draws both...

for packages, use `'corechart'` or `'line'` for *material*
if using *material*, don't forget `google.charts.Line.convertOptions`

however, there are several `options` that won't work in *material*
recommend using *corechart* with option for `theme: 'material'`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Dato');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Anbefalet pris');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Nuværende pris');

    data.addRows([
      [new Date (2016, 8, 6), 378, 418],
      [new Date (2016, 8, 13), 66, 324],
      [new Date (2016, 8, 20), 254, 257],
      [new Date (2016, 8, 27), 117, 105],
      [new Date (2016, 9, 3), 119, 66],
      [new Date (2016, 9, 10), 88, 77],
      [new Date (2016, 9, 17), 76, 96],
      [new Date (2016, 9, 24), 123, 106],
      [new Date (2016, 10, 1), 66, 148],
      [new Date (2016, 10, 8), 128, 116]
    ]);

    var tickMarks = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
      tickMarks.push(data.getValue(i, 0));
    }

    var options = {
      chart: {
        title: 'Anbefalede og nuværende ugepriser',
        subtitle: 'Blå: Anbefalede priser, Rød: Nuværende priser'
      },
      legend: { position:'none' },
      width: '100%',
      pointSize: 10,
      explorer: { actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'] },
      hAxis: {
        format: 'MM/dd/yyyy',
        ticks: tickMarks
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Line(document.getElementById('linechart_material'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Line.convertOptions(options));
    chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('linechart_core'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages: ['corechart', 'line']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div>Material Chart</div>
<div id="linechart_material"></div>
<div>Core Chart</div>
<div id="linechart_core"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to change the ticks on the x-axis. For example from Sundays to Mondays?

Comment: looks like the default _is_ to show Mondays, at least when I run the example above -- but the only way to customize what dates appear on the x-axis is to provide the specific dates in an array to the [config option](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options) `hAxis.ticks`...

Comment: OK, thanks. For me it's Sundays. What I would really like is for the ticks to match the data points, but I guess it's not possible...

Comment: adding ticks from the data points is easy, compared to adding Mondays, changed answer above to incorporate, note that only takes affect on _core chart_